# How to represent output in use case diagram

Tags: java, uml, message-queue

I am designing a use case diagram for system and doesn't know how to represent its output.

Here's what system is supposed to do.

(1) Run on different server and will be part of another product maintained by entirely different team in organisation.
(2) Gather information and send it to message queue which will be part of my product maintained by my department.

I want to show explicitly in use case that there will be two different systems here and my application will run on client system and send message to message queue in different system. I am confused in how to show message queue is part of another system.

Shall I just have a use case showing only message queue in another system and connect it to user case in client system ?

Thanks

Comment: I would draw 2 use case diagrams. One for your system (with their system as an actor) and one for their system (with your system as an actor). Both use cases could be illustrated by one (shared) sequence diagram

Answer (score 2):

Use cases are not about architecture/technical aspects. Use cases are about the added value of the system. Neither of your 2 cases is about the added value but about its architecture (the 2nd could be re-formulated to be a use case `Gather information`, but that's a commonplace). Place them in a component diagram to show how its deployed. However, you should start over thinking what the actual added value is for the actors of you system under consideration.

Answer (score 2):

If you interact with external system (e.g. send some messages to its queue), you depict that system as actor involved in Use Case.

You don't show on UC diagram that your system is "spread" on several servers. This is presented on deployment diagram.

Answer (score 0):

For your need sequence diagram might better emphasise the process part. I'm not sure if I get your systems right, but [this](http://www.planttext.com/planttext?text=VPB1JiCm38RlUGghdFS27AP9Eo0EdHX1ui1s29tfh3L9STp2tXwJ0ksW8fT4yUV__nrbbSInTBunvZc-Gx5k28CKSFLu947humbDgmHLrBeWK6pm3T8v2Ve2N8ADDHWEeBrV_T4hT_v7eCIKN8tmsc67MQFSNX8MkKUUkjZHnTGSknPkmqjaxuHYWDh94Pb2RG2U5alD1DVmG1vPBrmbr3l1pwIWIulVo4tk0ngb9aIvLS9APDo5AZyACAQk4MKEUAcgsUPojHmh7NO8jbyixMmkE-Ioe-iz2XFslurJvfHGBakj_rO7bLoz6zndHJAsruEEgE5tOOmwuIPZsfynZLdfhX_c0m00) simple example may help:

[image: Sequence diagram example]